# Component Caption + Custom Component Page height

Tags: inno-setup

I have two [@Martin Prikryl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/850848/martin-prikryl) codes that I can't get them to work together.

1. [Larger "Select Components" page in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20584671/larger-select-components-page-in-inno-setup)
2. [Long descriptions on Inno Setup components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867087/long-descriptions-on-inno-setup-components)

I followed all the instructions Martin said about the [@TLama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/960757/tlama) code, but the codes didn't work together.

Component captions do not appear when I activate the code to change the page height.

I would like a way to merge them and make them work together.

Comment: Show us [mcve] and tell us what exactly *"didn't work"*.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding the page's custom height value to the `CompLabel.Top` of the component captions code.

I also had to change the procedure to `CurPageChanged` and created an `<event( ' ' )>` to merge the two codes and created a directive `#define CustomPageHeight "ScaleY(200)"` to define the custom height of the page.

```pascal
                        // Set page height here
#define CustomPageHeight "ScaleY(200)"

[Code]

// Final part of code for component captions

Var StopCall: Boolean;
    <event('CurPageChanged')> // Added event here
Procedure CurPageChanged1(CurPageID: Integer);
Begin
  If StopCall = false Then
    Begin
      If CurPageID = wpWelcome Then
        Begin
          SetTimer(0, 0, 50, CreateCallback(@HoverTimerProc));

          CompLabel := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
          CompLabel.Parent := WizardForm.SelectComponentsPage;
          CompLabel.Left := WizardForm.ComponentsList.Left;
          CompLabel.Width := WizardForm.ComponentsList.Width;
          CompLabel.Height := ScaleY(37);                                                   // Added here
          CompLabel.Top := WizardForm.ComponentsList.Top + WizardForm.ComponentsList.Height + {#CustomPageHeight} - CompLabel.Height;
          
          CompLabel.AutoSize := False;
          CompLabel.WordWrap := True;

          WizardForm.ComponentsList.Height := WizardForm.ComponentsList.Height - CompLabel.Height - ScaleY(2);
          StopCall := true;
        End;
    End;
End;

// Code for custom height page 

var
  CompPageModified: Boolean;
    <event('CurPageChanged')> // Added event here
procedure CurPageChanged2(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurpageID = wpSelectComponents then
  begin                                     // Changed here
    WizardForm.Height := WizardForm.Height + {#CustomPageHeight};
    CompPageModified := True;
  end
    else
  if CompPageModified then
  begin                                     // Changed here
    WizardForm.Height := WizardForm.Height - {#CustomPageHeight};
    CompPageModified := False;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I wasn't clear enough for anyone to help me, so I solved it myself! 