# Inno Setup: Resize uninstall progress form with all its components

Tags: inno-setup, uninstallation

Hey I need to increase width and height of `UninstallProgressForm` of my Inno Setup uninstaller.

When I changed its width and height manually according to my custom - designed installer wizard page width and height, uninstall progress form appeared weird.

Only changed thing is its width and height. All other components like uninstall progress bar, title, captions, details, buttons remain with theirs old default size.

[image]

I like to know how can I resize all the components.

Thanks in advance.

***UPDATED QUESTION***

[image: - This is an image of my Installing page.]

It has a `Strectched WizardSmallBitmapImage` , an `Applogo (it is also a bitmap)` , and more long `cancel button`.

I like to have those also in my `UninstallProgressPage`.

How can I resize those components in to the `UninstallProgressForm` to become similar to the components' size in `Installing Page`?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to increase sizes or shift positions of all window components, one by one. For list of components, see a definition of the [`TUninstallProgressForm` class](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TUninstallProgressForm):

```pascal
TUninstallProgressForm = class(TSetupForm)
  property OuterNotebook: TNewNotebook; read;
  property InnerPage: TNewNotebookPage; read;
  property InnerNotebook: TNewNotebook; read;
  property InstallingPage: TNewNotebookPage; read;
  property MainPanel: TPanel; read;
  property PageNameLabel: TNewStaticText; read;
  property PageDescriptionLabel: TNewStaticText; read;
  property WizardSmallBitmapImage: TBitmapImage; read;
  property Bevel1: TBevel; read;
  property StatusLabel: TNewStaticText; read;
  property ProgressBar: TNewProgressBar; read;
  property BeveledLabel: TNewStaticText; read;
  property Bevel: TBevel; read;
  property CancelButton: TNewButton; read;
end;
```

The code can be like:

```pascal
const
  DeltaX = 150;
  DeltaY = 50;

procedure IncWidth(Control: TControl);
begin
  Control.Width := Control.Width + DeltaX;
end;

procedure IncHeight(Control: TControl);
begin
  Control.Height := Control.Height + DeltaY;
end;

procedure IncLeft(Control: TControl);
begin
  Control.Left := Control.Left + DeltaX;
end;

procedure IncTop(Control: TControl);
begin
  Control.Top := Control.Top + DeltaY;
end;

procedure IncWidthAndHeight(Control: TControl);
begin
  IncWidth(Control);
  IncHeight(Control);
end;

procedure InitializeUninstallProgressForm();
begin
  IncWidthAndHeight(UninstallProgressForm);
  IncWidth(UninstallProgressForm.Bevel);
  IncLeft(UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton);
  IncTop(UninstallProgressForm.CancelButton);
  IncWidthAndHeight(UninstallProgressForm.OuterNotebook);
  IncWidthAndHeight(UninstallProgressForm.InnerPage);
  IncWidth(UninstallProgressForm.Bevel1);
  IncWidthAndHeight(UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook);
  IncWidth(UninstallProgressForm.ProgressBar);
  IncWidth(UninstallProgressForm.StatusLabel);
  IncWidth(UninstallProgressForm.MainPanel);
  IncLeft(UninstallProgressForm.WizardSmallBitmapImage);
  IncWidth(UninstallProgressForm.PageDescriptionLabel);
  IncWidth(UninstallProgressForm.PageNameLabel);
  IncTop(UninstallProgressForm.BeveledLabel);
end;
```

[image: Larger uninstall window]

---

See also [How to change wizard size (width and height) in an Inno Setup installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11778292/850848)

Comment: Thank you , but this form looks very different from my installer wizard pages' forms , So I like to look this `UninstallProgressForm` similar to my `InstallingPage`.Please can you see my updated question.

Comment: This is not what you have asked for originally. You cannot change your question. And anyway, so just apply the same changes to your uninstaller as you did to your installer. We are not a code writting service.