# How to resize Inno Setup wizard pages?

Tags: inno-setup

I already know that wizard pages do not autosize with `WizardForm`.

I change size of `WizardForm` and insert background image at `WizardForm`.

Like this...

[image]

If I insert background image at `WizardForm.InnerPage`, then I get this

[image]
I want full background image.

Comment: So what do you want the wizard pages to look like? They are designed for a specific size. They won't look good, if you resize them.

Comment: See [How to change wizard size (width and height) in an Inno Setup installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11778292/850848)

Answer (score -1):

Did you try the Inno Setup extension specially designed for this purpose.

It is called Graphical Installer: http://www.graphical-installer.com

Please try it and let me know, I spent some time on its development.