# How to reduce the line spacing between two input boxes on Inno Setup TInputQueryWizardPage (CreateInputQueryPage)

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

I have a `TInputQueryWizardPage` page with 8 user inputs. The [wizard page has been increased](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11778292/) but still all the values are not visible. Is there a way to reduce the line spacing between two values so that all the values will be displayed with the current wizard size?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TInputQueryWizardPage.Edits` and `TInputQueryWizardPage.PromptLabels` to access the controls and re-locate them as you need:

```pascal
[Code]

procedure ReducePromptSpacing(Page: TInputQueryWizardPage; Count: Integer; Delta: Integer);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 1 to Count - 1 do
  begin
    Page.Edits[I].Top := Page.Edits[I].Top - Delta * I;
    Page.PromptLabels[I].Top := Page.PromptLabels[I].Top - Delta * I;
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  Page: TInputQueryWizardPage;
begin
  Page := CreateInputQueryPage(wpWelcome,
    'Personal Information', 'Who are you?',
    'Please specify your name and the company for whom you work, then click Next.');

  Page.Add('Prompt 1:', False);
  Page.Add('Prompt 2:', False);
  Page.Add('Prompt 3:', False);
  Page.Add('Prompt 4:', False);
  Page.Add('Prompt 5:', False);

  ReducePromptSpacing(Page, 5, ScaleY(10));
end;
```

Standard layout:

[image]

Layout with the spacing reduced by 10 pixels:

[image]